# Vuforia Image Target not showing cube on HoloLens/or not detecting physical Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

so i am trying to get my Image Target working, but nothing happens. So i am working on the HoloLens 2 and am using Unity. Here things i already checked:

1. Vuforia Key is added
2. in the Target Database it has 5*
3. AR Camera is in the scene under the object MixedRealityPlaySpace

Now i think it maybe be a problem with on of my settings so here are the settings or set up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l9lP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QlbN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XyBK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I040O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkp1K.png)

The cube is not added in this scene, but when i add it as child of the Image Target it still does not work.I am trying to track a phyisical Dartboard could that maybe not work with an Image Target?

Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

Image Targets are designed for tracking planar objects, for tracking a physical 3D object it would be better to use a Model Target.

To try and get your setup working I would suggest testing it in the Unity editor using a local webcam and see if your Image Target is detected there. If that works you should try a phone/tablet and if that also works then Hololens should work.